# How to make a CoreData sort

Tags: swift, core-data

I´m building an App with CoreData. I want to sort my CoreData data by date. I have already tried this:

```
func getData() {
  let request = NSFetchRequest<Session>(entityName: "Session")
  let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
  request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

  do {
    sessions = try contains.viewContext.fetch(request)
    print("Got \(sessions.count) sessions")
    tableView.reloadData()
  } catch {
    print("Fetch failed")
  }
}
```

But it shows the following error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSFetchRequest' by the request`.

Comment: Add `import CoreData`

Comment: then I get a new fail "Value of type '(UIFocusEnvironment) -> Bool' has no member 'viewContext'"

Comment: `contains.viewContext` is supposed to be the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance of the Core Data stack

Comment: what does that mean? sorry I'm very new in programming.

Comment: It depends on where your Core Data stack is located.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an `NSManagedContext` which may look something like:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

And, of course, a variable for the `NSManagedObjects` that are returned:

```
var sessions: [NSManagedObject] = []
```

Then you need to use it like this:

```
func loadQuotes() {
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Session")
   let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
   do {
      sessions = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
      } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Fetch failed")
   }
}
```